# Value of reference type before "new" keyword

Tags: c#, heap-memory, reference-type

I would like to clarify following. I know that reference type variable contains reference to block of memory which can contain value of that type. But before that value is assigned by using "new" keyword, the reference just points to empty place in memory?

Answer (score 6):

Unassigned fields are `null` references.
You can think of a `null` reference as pointing to nowhere.

Comment: Note that this only applies to fields of an object - uninitialized local variables aren't guaranteed to have any particular value.

Comment: @Anon: That's not true.  The CLR will assign default values to locals.  However, the C# compiler won't let you see them.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592274/initializing-null-variables-in-net/3592448#3592448

Comment: @SLaks: The C# spec doesn't require default initialization. The fact that the compiler emits `.locals init` anyway is an implementation detail.

Comment: @SLAks: Thanks. And if I use unassigned variable of reference type?

Comment: @Kalamaro: They'll be `null`.  If you try to use an instance member, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Anon: What are you talking about?

Comment: @SLaks: Local variables are not guaranteed to be default initialized. Microsoft's C# compiler does so, but that's an implementation detail, not guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: @Kalamaro, the compiler will complain if you try to use a local that cannot be proven to be definitely assigned. It's not enough to assign a variable, it must be proven to be assigned. As in `Foo foo; if (bar) { foo = new Foo(); } DoSomething(foo);` The compiler will scream because `foo` cannot be proven to be assigned when used as a parameter in `DoSomething`.

Comment: @Anon: Wrong.  The CLR guarantees this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592274/initializing-null-variables-in-net/3592448#3592448

Comment: @SLaks: Take a look at the CLI spec - 25.4.4 specifies a `CorILMethod_InitLocals` flag in the method header, and locals are not autoinitialized if that flag is not set.

Comment: @Anon: You're right that `InitLocals` isn't strictly required by the CLI spec, but any code that doesn't use it will be unverifiable. So emitting `InitLocals` *is* an implementation detail, but an implementation detail that's guaranteed by every language/compiler that produces verifiable code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a null for reference types, and default(type) for value types.
However, the compiler will prevent you from using unassigned <strike>fields and</strike> variables.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that *fields are always assigned*, so it is not possible to see an "unassigned" field. Fields are assigned to their default values by the memory manager when the storage for the field is obtained.